# Get a Query right in Parse REST API

Tags: php, rest, parse-platform

I implemented a query for chat messages in PARSE using their REST API. My problem is, I am getting messages where somehow sender and receiver was the same.

Clearly a bug or a test in the debug version. Anyway, those messages should not get displayed.

Obviously I want to fix that by changing my PARSE Query and not go through all the messages and delete the wrong ones. Is that even possible? I am not very good with the PARSE REST API.

This is what I am passing to PARSE API:

```
         $aWhere = array(
                        self::FIELD_SENDER =>   array('$in' => array($sUsername1, $sUsername2)),
                        self::FIELD_RECEIVER => array('$in' => array($sUsername1, $sUsername2)),                    
                    );  

$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/test?where='.json_encode($aWhere);
```

url then gets passed into CURL

I want to avoid messages where `self::FIELD_SENDER` is `$sUsername1` AND `self::FIELD_RECEIVER` is `$sUsername1` and the same goes in respect to `$sUsername2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend you instead fix your data using a Job.

As for what you are asking for, you can't quite get what you want. Let's explore the logic:

- You could try building an OR query

  - Query1: sender != user1 AND receiver != user1
  - Query2: sender != user2 AND receiver != user2

This may seem like it will give the results you want, except the situation excluded by Query1 is satisfied by Query2 and vice versa.

What about using $nin (not in):

- sender not in (user1, user2)
- receiver not in (user1, user2)

Unfortunately this will also exclude the following messages:

- sender=user1, receiver=(anyone)
- sender=user2, receiver=(anyone)
- sender=(anyone), receiver=user1
- sender=(anyone), receiver=user2